# Why does RenderItem need item deconstructed but keyExtractor doesn't in a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand deconstructing, but I'm trying to understand why in a FlatList component one prop would need to deconstruct and another wouldn't when they both have access to the same data.

For example in a FlatList component in React-Native why does renderItem need to deconstruct `item` but keyExtractor doesn't?

Example code

```
const data = [
  { id: "1", text: "Item 1" },
  { id: "2", text: "Item 2" },
  { id: "3", text: "Item 3" },
];
 
// ---- APP COMPONENT ----
 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <div>{item.text}</div>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    />
  );
};
 
export default App;
```

P.s. I'm just trying to understand something and I have read the react doc's for render props, I understand FlatList is just a wrapper component that exposes a bunch of props to work more easily with the list data, but I don't get why renderItem and keyExtractor have to act differently when using that data.

I've tried to read the React docs to get a better understanding and googling this specific issue hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason renderItem and keyExtractor behave differently is because they serve different purposes:

**renderItem** is responsible for defining the UI representation of each item in the list.

**keyExtractor** is responsible for providing a **unique identifier** for each item to aid React in efficiently managing and updating the list.

Comment: But they both grab ```item``` from the data prop right? So why does one need to deconstruct it and the other one doesn't is what I mean. After they have it I understand they use it in different ways.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that both `renderItem` and `keyExtractor` utilize the `data` prop, but they handle it differently due to their distinct purposes within the `FlatList` component.